# What to do with "The input line is too long" error message?

Tags: python, command-line, windows-console

I am trying to use os.system() to call another program that takes an input and an output file. The command I use is ~250 characters due to the long folder names.

When I try to call the command, I'm getting an error: `The input line is too long`.

I'm guessing there's a `255 character limit` (its built using a C system call, but I couldn't find the limitations on that either).

I tried changing the directory with `os.chdir()` to reduce the folder trail lengths, but when I try using `os.system()` with `"..\folder\filename"` it apparently can't handle relative path names. Is there any way to get around this limit or get it to recognize relative paths?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the subprocess module instead.  See [this](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) little doc for how to rewrite os.system calls to use subprocess.

Comment: WARNING: this is not a solution, please check next answer and you will discover that there is a bug in windows API, triggered when you use double quotes in command lines.

Answer (score 21):

Even it's a good idea to use `subprocess.Popen()`, this does not solve the issue.

**Your problem is not the 255 characters limit**, this was true on DOS times, later increased to 2048 for Windows NT/2000, and increased again to 8192 for Windows XP+.

The **real solution** is to workaround a very old bug in Windows APIs: [_popen() and _wpopen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx).

If you ever use quotes during the command line you have to add the entire command in quoates or you will get the `The input line is too long` error message.

All Microsoft operating systems starting with Windows XP had a 8192 characters limit which is now enough for any decent command line usage but they forgot to solve this bug.

To overcome their bug **just include your entire command in double quotes**, and if you want to know more real the [MSDN comment on _popen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx).

Be careful because these works:

```
prog
"prog"
""prog" param"
""prog" "param""
```

But these will not work:

```
""prog param""
```

If you need a function that does add the quotes when they are needed you can take the one from http://github.com/ssbarnea/tendo/blob/master/tendo/tee.py

Comment: @Sorbin - This was a huge help. I used it on Windows7 without any of the stuff you were talking about above. One thing I did have to do was add an extra double quote to the start. i.e. """prog" "param"". Not yet sure why that is so, I have my hunches and will prove /disprove those now.

Comment: His problem was "The command line is too long" not "The input line is too long"

Answer (score 2):

You should use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead of os.system.

subprocess has the advantage of being able to change the directory for you:

```
import subprocess
my_cwd = r"..\folder\"
my_process = subprocess.Popen(["command name", "option 1", "option 2"], cwd=my_cwd)
my_process.wait() # wait for process to end
if my_process.returncode != 0:
    print "Something went wrong!"
```

The subprocess module contains some helper functions as well if the above looks a bit verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using windows, from the backslashes, you could write a .bat file from python and then `os.system()` on that.  It's a hack.

Comment: .bat file does not accept commands longer than 8192 characters either.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you're using '\' in your strings that they're being properly escaped.

Python uses the '\' as the escape character, so the string `"..\folder\filename"` evaluates to `"..folderfilename"` since an escaped f is still an f.

You probably want to use

```
r"..\folder\filename"
```

or

```
"..\\folder\\filename"
```

Comment: yeah, I'm using raw strings, good catch for me not mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message but it was strange because the command was not that long (130 characters) and it used to work, it just stopped working one day.
I just closed the command window and opened a new one and it worked.
I have had the command window opened for a long time (maybe months, it's a remote virtual machine).
I guess is some windows bug with a buffer or something.

Comment: It is because invoking set `mypath=%mypath%;appendix` makes your path appendix longer every time you call it. Ultimately, guess what, it becomes too long. This where your windows leaks a bug. This question elaborates your problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630441